# LISP cdr function

Tags: lisp, cdr

If I do

```
(setq x   '(NOT (NOT (NOT (NOT A)))) )
```

`(cdr x)` is `(NOT (NOT (NOT A))))`

but `(cdr (cdr x))` is `NIL`

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um, it shouldn't. `(cdr x)` should give you `'((NOT (NOT (NOT A))))`.
Which means `(NOT (NOT (NOT A)))` is the first element of `(cdr x)`. When you cdr again it's on a one-element list, so you get nil `'()`

Comment: And if you explain a little more, it will show why (cdr (cdr x)) is NIL.